# How to convert NSMutableArray to CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, coordinates, cllocation, valueconverter

I have NSMutableArray:

```
        userCoordinates = [[d objectForKey:@"geo"] objectForKey:@"coordinates"];

        NSLog(@"%@",userCoordinates);
```

NSLog shows:

```
(
    "19.365367",
    "-99.159887"
)
```

Then I need to convert this array to CllocationCoordinate2D to use it for create annotation.
Sorry my english. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your array contains two `NSString` objects - to convert them to the appropriate floating-point numbers, use the `doubleValue` method of `NSString`:

```
double lat = [(NSString *)[userCoordinates objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
double lon = [(NSString *)[userCoordinates objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];

CLLocationCoordinate2D coords = (CLLocationCoordinate2D){ lat, lon };
```